# Group By, Count and Delete on Consecutive Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking-functions

I have a tricky SQL question. This is based on SQL server 2008 R2.

From a Log table, I have to combine ***consecutive*** records which have the same messages (`MSG`), count how many messages are combined (`COUNT`), and then delete the duplicate messages. This also needs to be done within a date range, so that any records outside of that range is left alone.

To make this more understandable, here is a small example of the data:

```
ID  DATE       MSG  COUNT
1   2013-08-17 mail NULL
2   2013-08-17 mail NULL
3   2013-08-17 www  NULL
4   2013-08-18 www  NULL
5   2013-08-18 www  NULL
6   2013-08-18 www  NULL
7   2013-08-18 mail NULL
8   2013-08-18 www  NULL
9   2013-08-19 mail NULL
10  2013-08-19 mail NULL
11  2013-08-20 mail NULL
12  2013-08-20 mail NULL
13  2013-08-21 www  NULL
14  2013-08-22 mail NULL
15  2013-08-22 mail NULL
16  2013-08-23 mail NULL
17  2013-08-23 mail NULL
18  2013-08-23 mail NULL
```

The result should look like the followng:

```
ID  DATE       MSG  COUNT
1   2013-08-17 mail NULL
2   2013-08-17 mail NULL
3   2013-08-17 www  NULL
6   2013-08-18 www  3
7   2013-08-18 mail 1
8   2013-08-18 www  1
12  2013-08-20 mail 4
13  2013-08-21 www  1
15  2013-08-22 mail 2
16  2013-08-23 mail NULL
17  2013-08-23 mail NULL
18  2013-08-23 mail NULL
```

So, basically, the query should

1. handle data only within a given date range (in this example from `2013-08-18` to `2013-08-22`)
2. combine consecutive rows based on the text of the `MSG` field
3. count the combined data and set the value in the `COUNT` field
4. delete the duplicate records (in this example e.g ID 6 stays, but ID 5 and ID 4 should be deleted)

As I am not an expert in SQL, I would really appreciate any help, suggestions or SQL queries.

Comment: Can you make a SQLFiddle? It would be much more easier for us to help you.

Comment: Are you looking for consecutive records or records on the same date, since in the query above it seems the records (MSG column) are grouped on the basis of date.

Comment: I am looking for consecutive records with same MSG (Message), not Date. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you running. SQL Server 2010 is not a known version

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to do it with 2 queries:

*(i)* The first one was to only count and update the records.

*(ii)* The second one was to delete all the records given the date range that had a `NULL` value on `COUNT` column.

**EDIT:** I did the step (i), but I couldn't make it keep the `COUNT` value `NULL` for the ones to be deleted. It updates all rows with the `COUNT`. Now you just have to `DELETE` the right rows.

Step *(i)*:

(For MySQL)

```
UPDATE tab ta JOIN 
    (SELECT date, msg, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tab GROUP BY date, msg) tb 
SET ta.count = tb.cnt 
WHERE ta.date = tb.date AND ta.msg = tb.msg AND 
ta.date BETWEEN 
    DATE('2013-08-18') AND DATE('2013-08-21');
```

**PS:** The syntax for `DATE` I used is for MySQL, you might adapt it for MS SQL Server.

(For MS SQL Server)

```
UPDATE ta 
SET ta.count = tb.cnt 
FROM tab ta, 
     (SELECT date, msg, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tab GROUP BY date, msg) tb 
WHERE ta.date = tb.date AND ta.msg = tb.msg AND ta.date 
BETWEEN CAST('2013-08-18' AS DATE) AND CAST('2013-08-20' AS DATE);
```

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question.

Comment: He also asked for **suggestions**. So... I think this is acceptable.

Comment: if you could help me with SQL code for (i), I could handle (ii)

Comment: @padre I'm trying it.

Comment: @padre Check out the step *(i)*. If you have problems with step *(ii)*, just ask here and I'll try to help you later.

Comment: @Lucas: Hi Lucas, the query does not give the wanted results. I think the first example was a bit confusing due to the DATE field. I posted another example, would preciate if you can come up with something for the second example. Thanks

Comment: @padre What does my query return to you? It is supposed to update all entries with the count and just later, remove the combined records.

Comment: I just checked here, the `TO_DATE` function is not working, check the edited.

Comment: let me check once agains

Comment: @padre I edited once again for the MS SQL Server syntax. Try the new one.

Comment: it counts ALL records with same MSG within the give date range, but it should count only CONSECUTIVE records with same MSG. I have posted another example to avoid confusion. Basically, if row1,row2 has "www" as MSG, and then row5 has "www" as MSG, it should set the count to 2 for row1 and row2, and the count to 1 for row5. In your example the count is set to 3 for row1, row2 and row5

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Sorry for misunderstanding it. I'll think again.

Comment: Hi Lucas, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see a way to do it with SQL queries. You will have to use Procedural Language.

Comment: yes, I was thinking the same, but I was hoping that I was missing something. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE #temp 
GO
select
    * 
into #temp
from (
    select '1' as id,'2013-08-17' as [date], 'mail' as msg,'NULL' as [count] union all
    select '2','2013-08-17','mail','NULL' union all
    select '3','2013-08-17','www','NULL' union all
    select '4','2013-08-18','www','NULL' union all
    select '5','2013-08-18','www','NULL' union all
    select '6','2013-08-18','www','NULL' union all
    select '7','2013-08-18','mail','NULL' union all
    select '8','2013-08-18','www','NULL' union all
    select '9','2013-08-19','mail','NULL' union all
    select '10','2013-08-19','mail','NULL' union all
    select '11','2013-08-20','mail','NULL' union all
    select '12','2013-08-20','mail','NULL' union all
    select '13','2013-08-21','www','NULL' union all
    select '14','2013-08-22','mail','NULL' union all
    select '15','2013-08-22','mail','NULL' union all
    select '16','2013-08-23','mail','NULL' union all
    select '17','2013-08-23','mail','NULL' union all
    select '18','2013-08-23','mail','NULL'
) x
GO


select 
    t.*,
    rwn
from #temp t
join (
    select 
        id, [date], [msg], [rwn] = row_number() over(partition by [date], [msg] order by id )
    from #temp
    where 1=1
        and [date] between '2013-08-18' and '2013-08-22'
) x
    on t.id=x.id
 order by 
    t.date, t.msg
```

Just modify it for UPDATE and then delete all rows where rwn>1

EDIT:
Your data type is probably text, so you get sort/comparison the errors. Do you really need text? It is a large object data type (blob), which can store several GB of text. Try changing this to varchar(8000) for example, or if these are really that big messages, varchar(max) will do, too

Comment: I have this error: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator

Comment: It complains about: (partition by DATUM,MSG order by id). If I remove the MSG from the Query, then I dont get any errors, but also no results

Comment: MSG is probably defined as `text` which you cannot sort or group on.  Try casting it to `varchar(max)` like: `cast(msg as varchar(max))`

Comment: no, my mistake ... it produce results, but the rwn is always set to 1

Comment: @padre Please see the edits. I explained the error, and posted runnable sql - works fine, so I don't know why you have rwn=1

Comment: I had to change the dates, however, the comparison should be performed only on the MSG field. I als edit the entry.

Comment: I also posted another example

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try this hope it helps you, The way i understand is  u need to group and remove duplicate and retain 1 only. sorry about my english

```
DECLARE @Table_2 TABLE (ID INT, [DATE] date, MSG Varchar(50), [COUNT] int)
Declare @fromDate as date = '2013-08-18'
Declare @toDate as date = '2013-08-22'

INSERT INTO @Table_2 (ID, [DATE], MSG, [COUNT])
SELECT     MAX(DISTINCT ID) AS ID, DATE, MSG, COUNT(DATE) AS COUNT
FROM         dbo.Table_1
where [DATE] between @fromDate and @toDate
GROUP BY DATE, MSG



UPDATE Table_1 
SET [COUNT] = T2.COUNT 

FROM Table_1 AS T1 INNER JOIN
@Table_2 AS T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID

WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID


DELETE T1
FROM Table_1 AS T1
FULL OUTER JOIN @Table_2 AS T2 
ON T1.DATE = T2.DATE AND T1.MSG = T2.MSG 

WHERE (T1.DATE = T2.DATE AND T1.MSG = T2.MSG) AND T1.ID != T2.ID
```